# Highcharts - too many series are displayed

Tags: highcharts

I want to manipulate the var series before I configure the highchart-code.

But I get 68 series!! instead of my 2 series I defined before.

What can be the error?

[image]

```
 var series;
 function refresher() {      
series = "[{ name = 'test1', data = data[0]},{ name = 'test', data = data[1]}]";          

        $.getJSON(url, 
        function(data) {            

        chart = new Highcharts.StockChart
        ({
        chart:  {  renderTo: 'container', zoomType: 'x',   type: 'line', width: 900 },  
        legend: { enabled: true, verticalAlign:'bottom' },
        title:  { text: 'You see the data of the last measured hour!' },  
        credits: { enabled: false  },           
        xAxis: {  type: 'datetime', title: { text: 'time'  } },
        yAxis: { title: { text: 'hallo'  } },       
        rangeSelector:{ enabled: false },
        navigator : { enabled: false },
        series: series,      
            tooltip: {  xDateFormat: '%e. %b.%Y  %H:%M:%S', valueDecimals: 2,  },   
        exporting: { enabled: true },
        });  
        // Format the y-data.
        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2, '.', ',');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `series` variable.

1st of all, it's a string, and not an object.

I don't know why you are using it like that but if you really want it to be a string, you'll have to `eval` it when given it to the `series` object:

```
...
series: eval(series)
...
```

Also, it's not:

```
series = "[{ name = 'test1', data = data[0]},{ name = 'test', data = data[1]}]"
```

The equal signs are incorrect.
It has to be:

```
series = "[{ name: 'test1', data: data[0]},{ name: 'test', data: data[1]}]"
```

(I've replaced the equal signs by colons.)

Comment: Someone from Highcharts-Team told me, that I can make it this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838742/can-i-use-different-if-conditions-in-highstock-code

Thanks! Now it works

Comment: Note that he doesn't mention a string anywhere. If you write it without quotation marks you'll be given it an object and you'll no longer have to eval it. But in that case you'll have to write the assignment inside the `getJSON` callback function because only then will `data` be defined. See lines 61 and 103 of [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/7gtga/3/) to see an example.